# How do i chain filter method for filtering an array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display an array, and filtered it by a search field and multiple dropdown, i have succesfully implemented the search field, but i don't know how to chain the dropdown to the filter function

In summary, I want to add another search parameter like a select or dropdown, how do i chain it with this filtered function?

```
const filtered = () => {
    if (search) {
      return data.filter((items) =>
        items.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
return data;
```

};

```
<form>
    <div className="form-grid">
        <select
            name="search"
            value={drop}
            className="form-control"
            onChange={handleDrop}
        >
            <option value="">ALL</option>
            <option value="new">RECENTLY ADDED</option>
            <option>SOON</option>
          </select>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search 160+ Data Source Connectors"
            onChange={handleSearch}
            name="search"
            value={search}
          />
          <select
            value={type}
            onChange={handleType}
            name="type"
            className="form-control form-select-lg"
          >
            <option value="">ALL</option>
            <option>APPLICATION</option>
            <option>FILE</option>
            <option>DATABASE</option>
            <option>EVENT</option>
          </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You want filtering of items to be done based on the search item from input as well as specific search types from the select field. Is that correct or do you want to update select fields based on the search term that was entered on your input?

Comment: I want the filtering of items to be done based on the search item from input as well as specific search types from the select field.

Comment: I have been able to solve it, thanks